# Select only first headline on entire page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to select the first headline (h2) and the **first headline only.**
I am able to select the headline(s), but because the headline is nested within seperate div elements, I am getting all headlines (which makes perfect sense).

I have tried selecting:

**CSS**

```
div.row:first-child h2:first-of-type {
// do stuff //
}
```

That's no good though, since there are many div's with a class of "row".

Currently I have this:

**CSS**

```
div.row h2:first-of-type {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Which is selecting both of my headlines (which I understand why). However, I only one the first one.

Thank you for your time!

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/n21ezsea/)

Comment: It isn't possible in pure CSS on an arbitrary HTML page if you don't know a few details about its structure. You should add a class when generating HTML code server-side or select it in JS/jQuery

Comment: I was hoping there was a magical way I hadn't thought of, but it's looking like I will in fact have to add some sort of hook.

Comment: The first heading of an HTML page should always be an H1: see http://webaim.org/techniques/semanticstructure/ for example (a level 2 heading should have a level 1 heading above/before it, an H4 should never follow an H1, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Given your HTML, why not do:

```
.row .row:first-of-type h2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

### [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n21ezsea/1/)

This selects the first `.row` within the parent wrapper `.row`, which given your HTML will contain the first `h2`. Simply change it to `.row .row:first-of-type h2:first-of-type` if it will contain more than a single `h2`

Comment: Unfortunately, since I'm using bootstrap, there are a lot of div's with a class of row. In some cases, there could be more or other times less - there isn't a fixed number. That's the tricky part I'm running into.

Worst case, I can just wrap my content area with a unique ID or something, but I was trying to make it a global setting without having to add another hook.

Answer (score 0):

SW4's answer works fine in this case, but if you ever change the HTML it will (likely) fail.

Can you add a class to the h2? That might be the easiest way of tackling this.

E.g.:

Some heading

Some heading

This way it's really easy to:

1. Style all headings with the `.heading` class
2. Style the main heading differently by using the `.heading--main` class, while keeping all styles from the `.heading` class.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below css, I used a dumy calss `.first`  you can also use id...

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 text-center">
                        <!-- image goes here -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 first">
                         <h2>My Headline</h2>

                        <p>My Text.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 text-center">
                        <!-- image goes here -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                         <h2>My Headline</h2>

                        <p>My Text.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the css

```
div.row .first h2:first-of-type {
    background-color: red;
}
```